# Trouble Rendering Checkboxes in JSReport

Tags: javascript, jsreport

I followed instructions to open developer tab > create textbox > create checkbox > edit properties & title.
My scenario: I have a survey, I am generating a docx report template with handlebars. This is a multiple choice question that has 2 options 1) general and 2)cultural.

doxc template:

```
{{docxCheckbox value=general}} General Monitoring
{{docxCheckbox value=cultural}} Cultural Resource Monitoring
```

json:

```
{
"general": "true",
"cultural": "false"
}
```

Does anyone have ideas or solutions?

[Error_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtcKg.png)